# How to make Uploadify work with Drag & Drop files?

Tags: jquery, file, upload, drag-and-drop, uploadify

How would I make Uploadify (http://www.uploadify.com/demos/) work with drag and drop files?

I'm trying to create exactly this using Uploadify: [image: uploadify example]

I just don't know how to start?

I assume that I will have to create instance using .uploadify() and I will have to use .uploadifyUpload() (triggers the file upload) for each dropped image in a loop. But how to do that to be cross-browser compatible? I already have working "select files" button that selects them and shows multiple uploading bars below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uploadify is a jQuery plugin which is based on Flash runtime so Drag&Drop is not supported. Yet.

If you wish to make a drag&drop, you have to use [Plupload](http://plupload.com/) and use HTML5, Gears and BrowserPlus as runtime (HTML5 won't work on IE).

See the table from [Plupload](http://plupload.com/) and you will see the features for each runtime.

Comment: Thank you but is there any workaround? I have uploadify implemented already and changing entire system to Plupload would be hard. Can't I trigger/imitate click + select somehow using jQuery?

Comment: you cannot use drag&drop with uploadify object. If the documentation doesn't mentioned that then this feature is unavailable. PLUpload seems with Uploadify with tiny modifications. PLUpload is used more because it supports many runtimes not as Uploadify which supports only one: Flash.

Comment: I rebuilt script and used Plupload. It is indeed a lot better. Thank you so much for your suggestion!